# Can SPL Mint Authority be a Program rather than a Signer?

Tags: spl-token, metadata

Trying to have a program control minting of tokens rather than a signer, but not sure how to sign with a program, ie when doing things like creating metadata for the token, since mintAuthority needs to be a signer.

Any way around this?

Comment: use a PDA, reference this (explore the repo it shows both native and anchor): https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/mint-2/anchor/programs/mint-2/src/instructions/mint_to_another_wallet.rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hi_I'mJohn answered this in comments, rewriting here to mark accepted answer:

The way to do this is to make a PDA of the Program the mint authority, then you can "sign" as the PDA by passing in signer seeds where needed.